# The precise definition of Normalization By Evaluation?

Tags: type-theory, pl.programming-languages, lambda-calculus, denotational-semantics, normalization

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalisation_by_evaluation) suggests that NbE is a technique for obtaining "the normal form of terms" by translating the object language into abstractions of the meta (host) language:

> The denotational semantics of (closed) terms in the meta-language interprets the constructs of the syntax in terms of features of the meta-language; thus, lam is interpreted as abstraction, app as application, etc.

One consequence is that we are now restricted to use [Higher-Order Abstract Syntax (HOAS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_abstract_syntax) to represent lambda terms, since De Bruijn indices and named representations are formally not "features" of the host language, e.g., Haskell. That article uses HOAS, accordingly.

Another publication (or rather a tutorial) called ["Checking Dependent Types with Normalization by Evaluation: A Tutorial"](https://davidchristiansen.dk/tutorials/implementing-types-hs.pdf), however, uses a bit different approach; in particular, it employs string variable identifiers instead of HOAS and a so-called "closure" construction, which is essentially a lambda abstraction packaged up with all the free variables occurring in its body:

```
data Value
  = VZero
  | VAdd1 Value
  | VClosure (Env Value) Name Expr
  | VNeutral Ty Neutral
  deriving (Show)
```

Another thing to note is that the closure's body is not fully evaluated even after invoking `eval` (under eager evaluation), as witnessed by the `Expr` type. Also, in the aforementioned Wikipedia article, `reflect` (`eval`) and `reify` (`readBack`) are mutually recursive, whereas in the Haskell tutorial only `readBack` calls `eval` when it encounters an unevaluated closure body. The author still recognizes the approach as NbE though.

Many NbE implementations that I was able to find throughout the Internet differ in these tiny but important aspects. I am therefore a tad perplexed with regard to what to call "Normalization by Evaluation". The only common thing I was able to notice is that all implementations include the evaluation (`eval`, `reflect`) and quoting (`readBack`, `reify`) functions which, when composed together, yield an interpreter.

In the PLT discourse, what is NbE exactly?

Comment: It's pretty much what you described. A method for finding normal forms by evaluating expressions to "some place" and then reconstructing the normal form from the result.

Comment: Ok, so basically NbE means that I have some "value" representation of an object language and two functions mapping a term to a value and vice versa; the rest of the stuff are just implementation details? In particular, if I employ the same approach as with closures, but fully evaluate the closure's body in `eval`, leaving its environment empty, can I still call this NbE?

Comment: As you said, it's a technique. I am not aware of a broad formal definition. Anything that is done in the spirit of existing examples can probably be called NbE.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference you see between higher-order and closure-based representations is a lot smaller than it first seems: the closure-based representation arises as the [defunctionalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defunctionalization) of the higher-order algorithm.

This was first introduced (to my knowledge) in Andreas Abel's 2013 habilitation thesis, [*Normalization by Evaluation: Dependent Types and Impredicativity*](https://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Eabela/habil.pdf)

Comment: Wow, thank you! I've heard about defunctionalization a bit, but the idea that closures are basically defunctionalized HOAS hasn't come to my mind...